# Python 3.2 lxml fill and submit form, select multiple, how to do it? value not working

Tags: forms, select, python-3.x, lxml

Great page this one, coming from the perl world and after several years of doing nothing, I've re-started to program again (this web page didn't exist, how things change). And now, after a 2 full-days of searching, I play the last card of asking here for help.

Working under mac environment, with python 3.2 and lxml 2.3 (installed following www.jtmoon.com/?p=21), what I am trying to do:

- web: http://biodbnet.abcc.ncifcrf.gov/db/db2db.php
- to fill the form that you find there
- to submit it

My code. I put several attempts and the output code.

```
from lxml.html import parse, submit_form, tostring
page = parse('http://biodbnet.abcc.ncifcrf.gov/db/db2db.php').getroot()
page.forms[0].fields['input'] = 'GI Number'
page.forms[0].inputs['outputs[]'].value = 'Gene ID'
page.forms[0].fields['hasComma'] = 'no'
page.forms[0].fields['removeDupValues'] = 'yes'
page.forms[0].fields['request'] = 'db2db'
page.forms[0].action = 'http://biodbnet.abcc.ncifcrf.gov/db/db2dbRes.php'
page.forms[0].fields['idList'] = '86439006'
submit_form(page.forms[0])
```

Output:

```
File "/Users/gerard/Desktop/barbacue/MGFtoXML.py", line 30, in <module>
page.forms[0].inputs['outputs[]'].value = 'Gene ID'
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 1058, in _value__set
"You must pass in a sequence")
TypeError: You must pass in a sequence
```

So, since that element is a multi-select element, I understand that I have to give a list

```
page.forms[0].inputs['outputs[]'].value = list('Gene ID')
```

Output:

```
File "/Users/gerard/Desktop/barbacue/MGFtoXML.py", line 30, in <module>
page.forms[0].inputs['outputs[]'].value = list('Gene ID')
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 1059, in _value__set
self.value.clear()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/lxml/html/_setmixin.py", line 115, in clear
self.remove(item)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 1159, in remove
"The option %r is not currently selected" % item)
ValueError: The option 'Affy ID' is not currently selected
```

'Affy ID' is the first option value of the list, and it is not selected. But what's the problem with it?

Surprisingly, if I instead put

```
page.forms[0].inputs['outputs[]'].multiple = list('Gene ID')
#page.forms[0].inputs['outputs[]'].value = list('Gene ID')
```

Then, somehow lxml likes it, and move on. However, the multiple attribute should be a boolean (actually it is if I print the value), I shouldn't touch it, and the "value" of the item should actually point to the selected items, according to the lxml docs.

The new output

```
File "/Users/gerard/Desktop/barbacue/MGFtoXML.py", line 87, in <module>
submit_form(page.forms[0])
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 856, in submit_form
return open_http(form.method, url, values)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 876, in open_http_urllib
return urlopen(url, data)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 138, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 364, in open
req = meth(req)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 1052, in do_request_
raise TypeError("POST data should be bytes"
TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be str.
```

So, what can be done?? I am sure that with python 2.6 I could use mecanize, or that perhaps lxml could work? But I really don't want to code in a sort-of deprecated version. I am enjoying a lot python, but I am starting to consider going back to perl. Perhaps this could be a smart movement??

Any help will be hugely appreciated

Gerard

- Reading in this forum, I find pythonpaste.org, could it be a replacement for lxml?

Comment: No Paste doesn't do any of the things lxml does. However, mechanize could. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/0.1.7b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing in a sequence to `list()` will generate a list from that sequence. `'Gene ID'` is  sequence (namely a sequence of characters). So `list('Gene ID')` will generate a list of characters, like so:

```
>>> list('Gene ID')
['G', 'e', 'n', 'e', ' ', 'I', 'D']
```

That's not what you want. Try this:

```
>>> ['Gene ID']
['Gene ID']
```

In other words:

```
page.forms[0].inputs['outputs[]'].value = ['Gene ID']
```

That should take you a bit forward.